# selecting the true height of a DIV in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, height

I have a DIV defined with a fixed height:

```
.w {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

if I put text in this it will hide everything that goes beyond the 100px. I have a button that shows all text, basically it does this:

```
$('.w').height('auto');
```

this will make all text visible, but I would like to animate this. And that won't work with height='auto', it has to have a specific height.

The question: how do I get the height the DIV should be to be able to show all text in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set the height to 'auto', then measure it, then set it back and start the effect.

Something like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ecoda/3)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Div starts with "style='height: 10px; overflow: hidden"
  var div = $('#thediv');

  // On click, animate it to its full natural height
  div.click(function() {
    var oldHeight, newHeight;

    // Measure before and after
    oldHeight = div.height();
    newHeight = div.height('auto').height();

    // Put back the short height (you could grab this first
    div.height(oldHeight);
    div.animate({height: newHeight + "px"}, "slow");
  });  
});​
```

Comment: div.height('auto').height() seems to work great! thanks for this solution. I think it's a bit more elegant than the div[0].scrollheight. Makes it more readable

Comment: This probably won't work if you have a `transition: height ...` css rule.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay - Probably not, no. But I figure if you have a CSS transition and/or animation, you're not going to use a jQuery animation as well...

Answer (score 15):

try `scrollHeight` like this:

```
$('#ID_OF_DIV')[0].scrollHeight
```

Note `[0]`, as it is property of DOM elements.

Comment: ok, this works indeed! is this array documented somewhere? I would never have guess this! ;-)

Comment: @patrick: *"is this array document somewhere?"* Yes, here's the link: http://docs.jquery.com/Types#jQuery A jQuery instance is (amongst other things) a pseudo-array of the DOM elements that are in the current set. So `var jqobj = $('#foo');` gives you a jQuery instance for the element with the ID "foo" (if any). You can access the raw element via `jqobj[0]`, and the number of matched elements via `jqobj.length`. **Unlike** a real array, you should treat the `length` property and the element entries as read-only. (cont'd)

Comment: (continuing) ..as read-only. Never do `jqobj.length = 3;` for instance, or `jqobj[0] = someElement;` (though you can do what you like, within reason, with the actual element at `jqobj[0]`). Always modify the contents of the jQuery instance via jQuery function calls. But accessing the raw DOM elements is documented and supported.

Comment: This works and should be the accepted answer! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder's answer didn't work for me because "oldHeight" was a calculated pixel value, different than the rem value I had specified in my stylesheet. Also, the inline style overrode a different height I had for another media query. So, instead of saving the "oldHeight" and putting it back later, I just cleared jQuery's inline style by setting css 'height' to an empty string.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // Div starts with "style='height: 10px; overflow: hidden"
    var div = $('#thediv');

    // On click, animate it to its full natural height
    div.click(function() {
        // Measure after
        var newHeight = div.height('auto').height();

        // Remove inline styles
        div.css('height', '');
        div.animate({height: newHeight + "px"}, "slow");

    });  
});​
```